# Animating & Filtering a list with images? Wordpress Portolio, Jquery, Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, css

I've seen this around lately, mostly in Wordpress, where portfolio listings are filtered but they have this neat animation during the filtering, this is [one of the nicer ones I've seen](http://themetrust.com/demos/filtered/).

So my question, how do you create this?

I am not really looking for all details but more of the logic behind animating the filtering process.  I can't really think of a way to pull that animation off.

Each portfolio item has inline positioning so somehow JS is figuring out where each item goes and animating moving it there.  I am guessing the solution would include jQuery, AJAX, CSS3...

Comment: Did you tried jQuery fadeOut and fadeIn methods?

Comment: Did you click the filters?  There is way more going on here beside fading an image in and out.  It does fade in and out but also slides to the correct position.

Comment: I did, but what exactly you are looking for in that animation?

Comment: I just don't get how this is being done.  So say you click on a filter, I assume this is using AJAX to return a list of portfolio items (divs with an image and text).  Normally those would all just show up however they fit into the DOM, there is something going on to give each item a nice slide into it's position.  Toggle back and forth between the all and branding filter to see what I am talking about.

Comment: take a look at this: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: That is interesting, I found http://isotope.metafizzy.co/faq.html which is the exact example.  I am still interested in the logic behind how this is done so I could create something like this without a plugin.